# Compile error, c++ OlcPixelGameEngine header file in use. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, header-files, fatal-error, gcc10, olcpixelgameengine

so the header file actually needs packages for it to work, I don't know how to install it that is why I am posting the error here.

```
-lGL -lpthread -lpng -lstdc++fs -std=c++17
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

these is the error statement found when I try to compile, please tell me how to install these libraries, BTW I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The dependencies are listed at the bottom of the wiki here: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/wiki

Comment: how do I download them?

Comment: `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev libglvnd-dev libpng-dev libxmu-dev` . ( libxmu-dev will install the most "X11" libraries as dependencies.)